# How to assign the value of a hidden field to the PHP Session on Click event?

Tags: php, html

I have following code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenfield" name="myhiddenfield" value="abc">
<a target="_blank" href="myfile.php" onClick="<?php $_SESSION['mySession'] = ??????? ?>">Click me</a>
```

How can I assign value of the hidden field (myhiddenfield) to the PHP Session on the click of an HTML link. I want to store "abc" in the PHP session.

Comment: something like... `onclick="form.submit();"` then in `myfile.php` -> `$_SESSION['mySession'] = $_POST['myhiddenfield']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to the web development, You cannot set server side(PHP) session from client code directly. Inorder to do this you can send data to the server either using post or get method.